# Display success error message from controller to vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using full calendar for displaying records and i am using drag and drop functionality of full calendar to update record dates.

I want that once update is successful success message should pass from controller to vf page and display in a pop-up and the same for error.

How to pass the message.

Full calendar Event drop :

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                    revertFunc();
                }

                var v =   moment(event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                var v1 =   moment(event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                var d= new Date(v1);
                d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
                v1= moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

                if(v1!='Invalid date' && v!=null){
                    setEvnt(event.id, v,v1); 
                }else{
                    setEvnt(event.id, v,v); 

                }
            },
```

Action:function:

```
        <apex:actionFunction name="setEvnt" action="{!setEvent}" reRender="calendar" >
            <apex:param value="" name="item" assignTo="{!eventIdTemp}" />
            <apex:param value="" name="test" assignTo="{!st}"/>
            <apex:param value="" name="test1" assignTo="{!ed}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
```

Controller -

```
public void setEvent() {

    try{

    for(Position_Reservation_Detail__c e : eventList) {  
            if(e.Id == eventIdTemp) { 
                e.End_Date__c = date.valueof(ed);
                e.Start_Date__c= date.valueof(st);
                update e;
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Saved successfully!'));
            }
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'unsuccessful!'));

    }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have an `<apex:pageMessages>` tag included on the page? You'll need to rerender that as well.

Comment: I should write the reRender in action:function for apex:message?

Comment: ok got it.. Can i have this message as a pop-up window as a <Div> tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `<apex:pageMessages>` tag and `rerender` it from your `<apex:actionFunction>`.

```
<apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />

...

<apex:actionFunction ... rerender="calendar, msgs" />
```

Comment: Thank u...Can i have this message as a pop-up window as a modal...

Comment: That is a completely different question. And I think you'll need to make an attempt yourself. But it sounds...non-trivial.